# VB.NET Forms Panel repeated grids height Sizing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm more of website developer with C# and having difficulty with VB.Net forms with VB.NET. Please review the screenshot. Parts blue color bar is header label in Panel. After that, there are some labels and then there is a Grid (LocationGrd). There are two rows, and I'm repeating the labels and location grid. How do I reduce the gap between the top and bottom boxes, there is too much gap between the first and second control boxes. Any clue?

```
For Index = 0 To Core.POParts.Count - 1
                        PartTypeDT = App.GetPartTypeForPart(Core.POParts(Index).PartNum, Core.POParts(Index).ProjectCodeOrSalesOrderID, Core.POParts(Index).IsProject)
                        '// Part Number
                    Core.PartNumLblArray.Add(GetLabel(PartNumLbl_Const, Index))
                    PartsPnl.Controls.Add(Core.PartNumLblArray(Index))
                    Core.PartNumTxtArray.Add(GetText(PartNumTxt_Const, Index, Core.POParts(Index).PartNum, Core.POParts(Index).PartID, MyBackColor))
                    PartsPnl.Controls.Add(Core.PartNumTxtArray(Index))
                         ......                             
                    Next

Private Function GetLocationsGrd(Index As Integer) As DataGridView
        Dim MyGrd As New DataGridView
        Dim MyLocationCol As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        Dim MyQuantityCol As New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()

        MyLocationCol.FillWeight = LocationCol.FillWeight
        MyLocationCol.HeaderText = "Location"
        MyLocationCol.Name = "LocationCol_" & Index

        MyQuantityCol.DefaultCellStyle = QuantityCol.DefaultCellStyle
        MyQuantityCol.FillWeight = QuantityCol.FillWeight
        MyQuantityCol.HeaderText = "Quantity"
        MyQuantityCol.Name = "QuantityCol_" & Index

        With MyGrd
            .AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
            .ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
            .Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {MyLocationCol, MyQuantityCol})
            .ContextMenuStrip = Me.ALContextMenuStrip
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationsGrd.Left, (Index * 200) + LocationsGrd.Top)
            .Name = LcationsGrd_Const & Index
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(LocationsGrd.Width, LocationsGrd.Height)
        End With

        Return MyGrd

    End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Do they look like this during design-time? If so, you can simply drag and drop the controls into your desired locations. If not, then you need to explain that in your question.

Comment: If you want a smaller gap then set the `Y` component of the `Location` properties of the bottom set of controls to a smaller value.  Are you perhaps saying, without actually saying, that you want the bottom set of controls directly under the top set and to then move down as rows are added to the upper grid?

Comment: Here is the code: I can't all all the code because of space limitation.

Comment: THe problem is, there is a location grid., however when the data repeats I'm not sure how the Part Number label row should be right below the first location grid. There is a too much gap, in previous code, sorry for indentation issue, FOr loop, I'm adding the data.

Comment: I added the code within the question. Good suggestion.

Comment: The code looks straight, not sure where the gap is.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I tried changing below, small location grid size reduced, but gap still maintained.   .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(LocationsGrd.Left, (Index * 200) + LocationsGrd.Top)

Comment: "The code looks straight". That's part of your problem right there.  You don't just READ the code.  You need to DEBUG it, i.e. set a breakpoint and step through it to see the actual course of execution and the values of the data being used AS IT IS BEING USED.  If you don't know how to debug, learn now, starting [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: I would guess that the issue is likely to be `Index * 200`.  200 pixels is a lot.  Of course, if you had debugged properly then you'd already know whether that expression produced the value you wanted.

Comment: I removed (Index * 200), it's only changing to location grid, I tried removing labels and text fields, still, the gap is there. Maybe I should try removing blue header Parts at the top. I'm debugging and came to this point (earlier I had no idea how to set heights, thanks for the comments to try with Y.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, I tried and it fixed Index * 110 for Location Grid as well as Labels and TextBoxes size. Good Suggestion.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Please hit answer your question, I will mark question as resolved.